# Can I add my own icon in font-awsome?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Can I add my own icon to font-awsome? I see from the site that I can post icon requests to github issues, but I did not see any relevant links.

I have looked at some of the [pull requests](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/pull/1329/files) and I see that `font/fontawesome-webfont.eot`, `font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf` and `font/fontawesome-webfont.woff` are binary files.

Where should I start looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you saw, Font Awesome icons are all in a custom font that the creators control.  If they won't accept your icon suggestion, you can create your own icon font.  Please see [this](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-turn-your-icons-into-a-web-font/).  The IcoMoon.io site they mention seems particularly interesting, but I have not used it yet.